# Can you explain why I get 2 different results passing the same structure in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, struct

Have been struggling with this so hope people can help me.
Suppose I have defined following structure

```
struct _SParticleEffect
{
    enumParticleTypes type;
    int count; 
    GLKVector3 initialPos; 
    GLKVector3 direction;
    float triggerRadius;
    CGSize prtSize; 
    float prtclSpeedMax;
    float prtclSpeedInitial; 
    float prtclLifeMax; 
    GLKVector4 color;
};
typedef struct _SParticleEffect SParticleEffect;
```

Then I make an instance of this structure and pass it to single function in two ways - by pointer and by value:

```
- (void) InitGeometry
{
    SParticleEffect splashEffect;
    splashEffect.count = 15;
    [splashPrt TestFunc: &splashEffect : splashEffect];
}

//test function with 2 parameters -  by pointer and by value
//method of splashPrt
- (void) TestFunc: (SParticleEffect*) attrPointer: (SParticleEffect) attr
{
    NSLog(@"1: %d", attrPointer->count);
    NSLog(@"2: %d", attr.count);
}
```

And this is the result I get

> 2015-07-01 16:58:28.766 [1738:707] 1: 15
>
> 2015-07-01 16:58:28.770 [1738:707] 2: 804245704

As you can see it seems like in the second case, 'count' is lost. The worst part is that this result is not consistent, because if I put this count parameter as first parameter of structure then in both cases result is 15.
Can you explain to me why this is or tell some way to try to debug it?

**How to reproduce error:**
To reproduce create single-view app from XCode (6.3.2.) template
Deplayment target to 6.0 , iOS base SDK 8.3

No changes in AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m.
Add new files ParticleEffect.h and ParticleEffect.m with following content

Content of ParticleEffect.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

struct _SParticleEffect
{
    GLKVector3 initialPos;
    int count;
    GLKVector3 direction;
    float triggerRadius;
    CGSize prtSize;
    float prtclSpeedMax;
    float prtclSpeedInitial;
    float prtclLifeMax;
    GLKVector4 color;
};
typedef struct _SParticleEffect SParticleEffect;

@interface ParticleEffect : NSObject
{

}

- (id) initWithAttributes:(SParticleEffect *)pointer viaCopiedStruct:(SParticleEffect)copiedStruct;
@end
```

Content of ParticleEffect.m

```
#import "ParticleEffect.h"

@implementation ParticleEffect


- (id) initWithAttributes:(SParticleEffect *)pointer viaCopiedStruct:(SParticleEffect)copiedStruct;
{
    NSLog(@"1: %d", pointer->count);
    NSLog(@"2: %d", copiedStruct.count);
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Content of file ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ParticleEffect.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Contents of file ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    ParticleEffect *splashPrt;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) ParticleEffect *splashPrt;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize splashPrt;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SParticleEffect splashEffect;
    splashEffect.count = 15;
    splashPrt = [[ParticleEffect alloc] initWithAttributes: &splashEffect viaCopiedStruct:splashEffect];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

No other changes in the project.
I run it on iPod 5, iOS 8.2, but appears on other devices too.
I get the following output:

```
2015-07-02 16:06:18.633 testStruct[617:96867] 1: 15
2015-07-02 16:06:18.637 testStruct[617:96867] 2: 715393
```

Comment: Vote to close, as "cannot reproduce".

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't show what you're doing. It gives "15" both times.

By the way, your coding style is way off, and you're breaking all naming conventions.

This is how it should be written the Objective-C way, which is much easier to read and understand, by the way.

```
- (void)initGeometry
{
    SParticleEffect splashEffect;
    splashEffect.count = 15;
    [splash testPassViaPointer:&splashEffect viaCopiedStruct:splashEffect];
}

- (void) testPassViaPointer:(SParticleEffect *)pointer viaCopiedStruct:(SParticleEffect)copiedStruct
{
    NSLog(@"1: %d", pointer->count);
    NSLog(@"2: %d", copiedStruct.count);
}
```

In short: method names start with lower case letters, nothing is abbreviated, parameters/arguments have names.

Comment: Thank you for response. I added how to reproduce error at the bottom

Comment: No, that code still works fine! Please copy and paste exact code to reproduce the problem - this might be enough to spot the difference and bug.

Comment: I am glad you are hanging in, I updated exact code. I hope you will reproduce the error

Comment: Again: Copy-Paste your exact code. Or upload your example project somewhere. Because the code posted *is* working.

Comment: This was exact copy-paste code. There is nothing more. If it is working for you then probably it is the worst case - compiler bug. It is interesting because if I change order of structure or remove some elements then it works for me too, but in this exact structure order there is error.

Comment: I'd bet this is *not* a compiler bug. Look at all compiler warnings, maybe the static analyzer brings something up. It sure looks like uninitialized data, wrongly referencing a pointer, or surpressed type information. (I assume you use latest Xcode and clang)